# Accessing RouterLinkActive in a nested component using Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular6

I have a list-group defined as a list of *recipe-items*. I'm using the child routing in order to display a description of the item whenever the user clicks on a list element. So far the click event and the routing are working but **I want to mark the clicked item as active**.

<kbd>recipe-list.component.html</kbd>

```
<app-recipe-item 
  *ngFor="let recipeEl of recipes; let i = index" 
  [recipe]="recipeEl"
  [routerLink]="i"
  style="cursor: pointer;"
  >
</app-recipe-item>
```

In order to do it I'm trying to use the [*routerLinkActive*](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) directive within my nested `RecipeItemComponent` but it looks like the directive is out of scope for the nested component.

<kbd>recipe-item.component.html</kbd>

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a 
    class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start"
    routerLinkActive="active"
    >
     TO BE MARKED AS ACTIVE WHEN CLICKED
  </a>
</div>
```

What am I missing? Even using a *localRef* it's impossible to retrieve its value in a nested component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`routerLinkActive`** directive add special styles to actived link by subscribing to router's navigate event, see **[source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_link_active.ts#L94)**.

You can do the same in your `app-recipe-item` component as well without using routerLinkActive directive.(code is the same)

---

Another way, `routerLinkActive` provides an [`isActive`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#properties) property which shows whether current routerLink is active or not. You can inject it as your component as well to retrieve its value and change to active style.

```
<app-recipe-item 
  *ngFor="let recipeEl of recipes; 
  let i = index" [recipe]="recipeEl" 
  [routerLink]="i" style="cursor: pointer;"
  routerLinkActive
>
</app-recipe-item>

constructor(
  @Inject(RouterLinkActive) private activeRouter: RouterLinkActive  // inject
) { }

<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start"
  [ngClass]="{active: activeRouter.isActive}"
>
  TO BE MARKED AS ACTIVE WHEN CLICKED
</a>
```

Refer **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-link-active?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnavigate.component.ts)**.

Comment: Thank you @Pengyy. My actual solution involved the use of `isActive` but  to conveniently use it I had to pass this boolean value to the child component `recipe-item`. So, the `recipe-list` takes advantage of the `RouterLinkActive` directive, setting a boolean property into the `recipe-item` => `routerLinkActive
      #rla="routerLinkActive"
      [currentlySelected]="rla.isActive"`

Comment: I've added my personal solution below just for reference an I'm going to accept your answer as a valid solution. ;)

Comment: @sentenza Thank you! BTW, nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using the `RouterLinkActive` directive and its property `isActive`

Using the `RouterLinkActive` and a local reference it's possible to pass the value of `isActive` to an `@Input()` property of the nested component in order to use it in its template to trigger `ngClass`.

*recipe-list.component.html*

```
 <app-recipe-item 
  *ngFor="let recipeEl of recipes; let i = index" 
  [recipe]="recipeEl"
  [routerLink]="i"
  routerLinkActive
  #rla="routerLinkActive"
  [currentlySelected]="rla.isActive"
  style="cursor: pointer;"
  >
</app-recipe-item>
```

*recipe-item.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-item',
  templateUrl: './recipe-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-item.component.css']
})
export class RecipeItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() recipe: Recipe;
  @Input() currentlySelected: boolean;
```

*recipe-item.component.html*

```
...
<a [ngClass]="{active: currentlySelected}">
...
```